# Problems of using Solidworks EDrawings 2018 viewer in windows application

Tags: c#, solidworks

I want to add EDrawings2018 viewer in my windows application. I took following steps:

1. Downloaded Edrawings2018
2. Installed it on my computer
3. Copied EModelView.dll from "C:\Program Files\Common Files\eDrawings2018\"
4. Added a reference of this dll in my application.
5. Compiled my application.
6. Now rightclick on ToolBox-->ChooseItems-->COM components but i stuck here i didnot find the edrawing control here.

Can you please help me ?

Comment: This link worked for me....  
[link](https://forum.solidworks.com/message/663391#comment-663391)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [link](http://my.solidworks.com/reader/forumthreads/207502/how-to-add-the-edrawings-activex-control-20162017-to-vbnet-) you might find useful.

A short summary : at some point they stopped providing x32 version of the control and because VS is a 32 bit application you can't use the toolbox to add 64bit eDrawings control.

Try using sample from the link, but note that you'll need to change GUID for eDrawings control as sample was written for 2016 version of eDrawings.

EDIT: For me guid from the sample worked (I have eDrawings 2017) but make sure your project is building against x64.